# Excel Reference error due to summing cells

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I think I broke Excel.

I've downloaded this [Template](https://templates.office.com/en-us/Family-Budget-Planner-TM10188408) to make a budget, but I'm customising it.

I've added a few more rows to one of the tables (Gifts and ...) and I had to re-add the 'Total Row' (and option on  the Table Tools, Design -> Table Style Options), to get the 'Total Projected Cost' and 'Total Actual Cost' to work, but the Difference Cell is showing `#Ref!`

I've stepped through the Show Calculation Steps, and these are the last two steps:

[image: Step showing -0.625+0]
[image: Last step shoing <code>#Ref!</code>]

How do I resolve this?

Comment: The problem was probably the removal and readding of the total row, i simply added a additional row by clicking on the carity 3 cell and inserted a new row, works like charm for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the columns above total, and the way these 'tables' seem to work in excel.

If you manually add a totals rows, there's a chance it will copy the formula to the cells above, without making it obvious what it's done.

Removing the total row (as I did) and adding the totals row properly, won't undo the copying of formulas.

The way I traced it down is looking into `Formulas -> Error Checking` menu option then selecting `Circular References`. It did also give me a warning when I re-opened the game.